# How to select the hour and minute in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I need to extract the hour and minute from a datetime in a query.

In MySQL I have it as 
    `SELECT id as id, date_format(etadate, '%m/%d/%Y') as etadate, date_format(etadate, '%H') as etahour, date_format(etadate, '%i') as etamin, ...`

However, Doctrine does not recognize the `date_format` when I tried to do a similar query:

```
 SELECT
    cfs.id as cfsid, cfs.etadate as etadate, 
    date_format(etadate, "%H") as etahour,
    date_format(etadate, "%i") as etamin
 FROM
    CFSBundle:Cfs cfs
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `date_format` Doctrine by creating an extension, or using a bundle that adds this for you.

To create your own extension, look at sample here - https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/DateFormat.php

How to register you extensions - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT` and various other functions are not included in [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html). So you need to use Doctrine’s [NativeSQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html) functions to write an SQL statement or write a User-Defined Function so that Doctrine recognises `DATE_FORMAT` when written in DQL and can successfully transform it into SQL.

See:: [Using DATE_FORMAT in Doctrine](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/)

[Date Format Class](https://github.com/uvd/Doctrine)